# Zoom position on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, zooming

I want to change, when I click on image, the hover image position. Now* the image hover enlarge on bottom, and I want with enlargement on top (see the image link).
I have added this code :

HTML:

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.image { background:url(image url); height:50px; width:50px; }

.image:hover { background:url( image url ); height:400px; width:400px; }
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 .image:hover {
cursor: pointer;
height:400px;
width: 400px;
transform:scale(1.5);
-ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
}
```

it works ..

Comment: I have fixed with this : .image:hover {
  background:url(http://www.url.com);
height:500px;
width: 400px;
margin-top: -250px;
  color: trasparent; 
}

Comment: ok but u don't need to call the image again in case you use different image you can use it r else its unnecessary  :)